# asp.net how to combine two datetime date to one datetime object?

Tags: asp.net, datetime

I have 
Datetime starttime='1/1/1900 6:00:00PM'
Datetime ExamDate='12/9/2013 12:00:00PM'

i want to combine these such that the result

Datetime combine=starttime+ExamDate;
so,
Result Datetime combine='12/9/2013 6:00:00PM'

Please help thank you

Comment: So are you only wanting to add the `starttime`'s time-portion to the `ExamDate`?

Comment: Your expected result isn't going to be achieved through standard DateTime arithmetic, the result of `12/09/2013 12:00:00PM` + `6:00:00PM` is actually `13/09/2013 6:00:00AM`, as 6PM is hour 18 of the day.  Can you explain why you're storing your starttime as a complete DateTime? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% certain if this is what you're trying to achieve, but I'll give it a shot. To add time to an existing `DateTime` object, use the `TimeSpan` class. Ex:

```
TimeSpan StartTime = new TimeSpan(0, 6, 0, 0); //new time span of 6 hours
// create date time 2013-09-12 12:00
DateTime ExamDate = new DateTime(2013, 9, 12, 12);
//Add the 6 hour time span to your exam date to get combined date
DateTime Combined = ExamDate + StartTime;
```

Comment: The OP's actually using `TimeSpan StartTime = new TimeSpan(0, 18, 0, 0);`, however, and this solution still wouldn't give him '12/9/2013 6:00:00PM' as a result.

Comment: No, the OP is not using any `TimeSpan`. This solution adds 6 hours to 12PM on 12/9/2013, which gives 6PM on 12/9/2013.

Comment: But his starttime does not represent TimeSpan(0, 6, 0, 0). It more closely matches TimeSpan(0, 18, 0, 0).  I'm assuming he's not hard-coding his start times, therefore any times that push his ExamDate to the next day might not be what's desired.

Comment: Also, he's wanting to combine two DateTime's into one.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd simply like to add the TIME portion of starttime to examDate

```
var startTime= DateTime.Parse("1/1/1900 6:00:00PM");
var examDate = DateTime.Parse("12/9/2013 12:00:00PM");
var result = examTime.Add(starttime.TimeOfDay);
```

This will result in: `13/9/2013 6:00:00AM`.

It's occurred to me you might just be trying to store the date in examDate, in which case setting examDate to `12/9/2013 12:00:00AM` will give:  `12/9/2013 6:00:00PM`.